# Watch movie while downloading when using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, vlc-media-player, streaming, chromium

I watch movies I download. I know that I can wait until the file is completely downloaded. But I usually don't do so.

I usually open the partially downloaded file by VLC or other player. It shows me warning that the file is not complete and that seeking might not work correctly. (But it does work until I try to seek to forward to area of movie which wasn't downloaded yet.)

I do this usually immediately after starting download. At least I used to do so.

The Chrome browser have had small problem with this approach when the download was completed. The file is named sligtly differently. It has the suffix `.crdownload` and the file should be renamed after the download is completed. Which the browser couldn’t do because the file was opened. So it showed the warning and I renamed the file manually.

Now I tried to use newer version of Chrome and it doesn’t work so flawlessly. At first sight it works. I wathed the movie. But when the download is completed it probably has again problem with renaming the file but now it has problem to even show me the warning and instead it deletes the downloaded contents and starts the download once again! What a nonsense. Is this a bug or a feature? Should I report the bug somewhere?

What should I do now? Use a different browser? I tried Chromium browser. But the new versions behave the same and have the same problem.

Or should I use old version of Chrome and Chromium? I have several years old version of them. I would love not to update and use that old browsers. But most webpages complain that they don’t support so ancient browsers.

So how do you do it?

Comment: Use wget for download, like: `wget http://cclicence.film/myfavourite.mp4 -O- | tee myfav.mp4 | mpv -` ...or any download manager.

Comment: I know about wget and this would definitely work. But I still believe that it should be done more user friendly way - inside a browser. Like it used to be until now. Maybe I should really report a bug to chrome or chromium.

Comment: You haven't said what OS you're using, though the `chromium` tag suggests it might be some form of Linux. If you're playing the file, I would not expect that that an open file could be deleted. My personal preference would be to copy the temporary file after it has been down-loading for a while, and play the copy. Depending on your level of impatience, by the time you get to the end of the copied segment the down-load may have completed, and you can resume your viewing from there. If not, copy again and play a bit more. Not exactly seamless, but minimum impact on down-load progress.

Comment: I doubt it's a bug: I wouldn't think that playing current down-loads would be supported in any way. One more thought: if you're on Linux, make a _hard_ link to the temporary file and play that (don't, of course, use the name and directory that the down-load will be renamed to).

Comment: “But I still believe that it should be done more user friendly way - inside a browser. Like it used to be until now. Maybe I should really report a bug to chrome or chromium.” This is not a bug. You are requesting a feature to change the way Chrome works so files can be opened while they are being downloaded.

Comment: Does this question come under web applications??  Moderators please note

Answer (score -1):

Just trace the file ending with .crdownload -> right click on the file -> in the "opens with" change button, select google chrome and then apply.
now double click the file which has chrome logio then the file plays in chrome simultaneously while downloading.

Answer (score -1):

In Linux, this is possible to rename already opened file (so you are free to watch video even downloading is in progress without worrying), but this is not possible in Windows. This is system-level problem or difference how the Linux/Windows handles opened file.

When the file download is finished, Chrome try to rename it from .crdownload to .avi (or so), but it fails so Chrome delete the file and restarts downloading. Chrome developers probably don't want to left unrenamed .crdownload file around (as the file may not be whole/finished/fullsize). You may close the file few seconds (or minutes) before downloading finishes (ie. close the video player) and wait until Chrome finishes its part and then watch the rest.